# How to make doctrine map array of ids that have references to another table

Tags: php, database, symfony

In symfony I am trying to store a json array of ids in field (relatedQuestions) of Entity (Question), those ids have reference to the related questions, which mean this is a recursive relationship, and I am trying to present it as an array of ids instead of a relationship (I don't wanna use OneToMany or ManyToMany or else I wouldn't be here asking).

So far so good,  storing them is easy but I have a problem I don't know how can I map those ids, because I have a form type (QuestionType), inside it I have a  relatedQuestions field of type Entity Type, multiple so the user can select the related questions to the current one that he is trying to add.

The field in my entity:

```
 /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="relatedQuestions", type="json", nullable=true)
     * Serializer\Type("array")
     * Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $relatedQuestions = [];
```

The field in my FormType:

```
->add('relatedQuestions', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Question::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'select-multiple hidden',
                    'default_option' => false,
                    'multiple' => 'multiple'
                ],
                ]);
```

Please tell me How can I do this in symfony?

I tried to find a hint in the doc and symfony casts, but I couldn't figure how can I map those ids.

Comment: I would add functions `getRelatedQuestionEntities()` that returns an array of `Question` entities, and `setRelatedQuestionEntities()`, that accepts an array of `Question` entities. In those functions, you would probably use the question repository to find the entities by reading the ids from your json. Forms use getters and setters if you provide them with a name that "has" them, so you could then just make `->add('relatedQuestionEntities', EntityType::class, [...])` and it will use the getters and setters. Be sure to add docblock typehints.

Comment: if you only really need the entities in the form and nowhere else, you can also use DataMappers: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html to transform the json into an array of entities and  vice versa, and keep your entity free from repository calls. Specifically the short version comes in handy: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html#mapping-form-fields-using-callbacks

Comment: @Jakumi can you explain the solution about using repository more, how can I use the repository inside my entity so I can retrieve the relatedQuestions?

Comment: Can you give me a code hint for getRelatedQuestionEntities() and  setRelatedQuestionEntities()
That will be awesome

Comment: okay, it's usually tricky (and ugly) to inject repositories into entities, but in your case, I don't see a clear way around it. You would have a [**postload**](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/events.html) Handler in your codebase, that would call a setter on the entity to give it the repository or the entitymanager. the getRelatedQuestionEntities would use getRelatedQuestions to hopefully fetch the ids and then use a findByQuestionId([id1,id2]) call on the repository to fetch the entities. The setter would be simple, just cycle through the entities and

Comment: pass the ids to your setRelatedQuestions function.